# Windows: Selenium webdriver.Firefox hangs

Tags: python, selenium

I am new to windows and this is the first time I am running a Python program on windows.

I am running a crawler program that uses selenium and firefox webdriver.
My program runs successfully on mac/ubuntu, but on windows

`webdriver.Firefox()`

open a new geckodriver window(cmd like window) and just hangs there nothing after that. Program doesn't move forward after that.

Windows 7
geckodriverv0.13

Comment: Do you have the latest Firefox and geckodriver?

Comment: No, not the latest firefox(49.02) the latest firefox was not opening on my windows 7 32 bit.

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is most likely the compatibility between Firefox and your GeckoDriver. Try using the latest Firefox and `geckodriver`. If you have a problem with Firefox, try reinstalling it and disable automatic updating.